# expected value of n-fold p-coin toss

Tags: probability

We have n-fold p-coin toss

Y is the number of ordered pairs of tosses in which both result in 1.

I need the expected value of Y where Y is a sum of indicator variables, and a proof that
$$ E[X(X-1)], \space X\space Bin-(n,p)-$$

---

$$ Y_i=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
1 && X_i = p\\
0 && X_i = (1-p)

\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Any sum of Bernoulli random variables, $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nY_i$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$. In other words, for every integer $k$ such that $0\le k\le n$,
$$
\mathrm P(S_n=k)={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
$$

But how can I show that the expectation value is $$E[X(X-1)]\space?$$

Comment: Can you find $g(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb{P}(S_n = k) t^k$. Then $\mathbb{E}(X(X-1)) = g^{\prime\prime}(1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sasha suggested, let $$\begin{align*}
g(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb{P}(S_n=k)x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k p^k(1-p)^{n-k}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k(px)^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\
&=(px+1-p)^n
\end{align*}$$ by the binomial theorem. Then 
$$g\;'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n k\mathbb{P}(S_n=k)x^{k-1}\;,
$$

and $$g\;''(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n k(k-1)\mathbb{P}(S_n=k)x^{k-2}\;,$$

so $$g\;''(1)=\sum_{k=0}^n k(k-1)\mathbb{P}(S_n=k)=\mathbb{E}(X(X-1))$$ by definition. On the other hand, you know that $g(x)=p(px+1-p)^n$, so you can calculate $g\;''(1)$ explicitly with a little elementary calculus.